# Get request for a custom url using the store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to send a GET request to a custom url at `this.get('/transactions/from/:startDate/to/:endDate');` using `this.store.query` function in Ember-data. How can that be accomplished?

Comment: override the `query` function in your adapter

Comment: Yeah, that is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 2):

In order to send a GET request for a custom URL, the `query` function in your adapter needs to be overridden. I had a model named `transaction`. So I wanted to do something like `this.store.query('transaction', { filterType: 'dateRange', startDate: '01-01-12', endDate: '12-31-12'}` and then have the GET request sent to `transactions/from/01-01-12/to/12-31-12`. Here is what I had to do to make it work:

```
query: function(store, type, query) {
    if (query.filterType && query.filterType === 'dateRange') {
      const url = `transactions/from/${query.startDate}/to/${query.endDate}`;

      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(data => resolve(data), err => reject(err));
      });
    } else {
      return this._super(store, type, query);
    }
  }
```

Comment: don't forget to return the result of `this._super(store, type, query);` ;)